# Sortable('toArray') or sortable('serialize')

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I read a few questions on Stackoverflow that recommend using serialize() and toArray with sortable() to prepare the data for insertion in a database. However, when I try to pass them to sortable('toArray') or sortable('serialize'), it breaks the code i.e. the list is no longer sortable. Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/sTzCS/16/

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<ul id="sortlist">
        <li id="Vancouver">Vancouver</li>
        <li id="Toronto">Toronto</li>
        <li id="Montreal">Montreal</li>
        <li id="Ottawa">Ottawa</li>
        <li id="Calgary">Calgary</li>
        <li id="Edmonton">Edmonton</li>
        <li id="Winnipeg">Winnipeg</li>
     </ul>​
```

JavaScript

```
// also tried $('#sortlist').sortable('serialize);

var result = $('#sortlist').sortable("toArray");

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how to do it

```
$("#sortlist").sortable({stop: function(event, ui) {
    result = $("#sortlist").sortable("toArray");
     alert(result.length);

}});
```

Comment: Consider using the `update` event instead of `stop` to reduce overhead--if the order doesn't change, you likely don't care about the event.

Answer (score 5):

Changed the li's ids from "Toronto" to "city_Toronto", etc.

```
<ul id="sortlist">
        <li id="city_Vancouver">Vancouver</li>
        <li id="city_Toronto">Toronto</li>
        <li id="city_Montreal">Montreal</li>
        <li id="city_Ottawa">Ottawa</li>
        <li id="city_Calgary">Calgary</li>
        <li id="city_Edmonton">Edmonton</li>
        <li id="city_Winnipeg">Winnipeg</li>
     </ul>
```

From the [jqueryui docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize):

> serialize works by default by looking at the id of each item in the
>   format "setname_number", and it spits out a hash like
>   "setname[]=number&setname[]=number"

Added an extra .sortable() in the jquery code to make the ul sortable as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1959893

```
var result = $('#sortlist').sortable().sortable("serialize");
```

(forked into http://jsfiddle.net/s8eJU/)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you should initialize the sortable,

```
$('#sortlist').sortable();
```

and then call the serialize.

```
var result = $('#sortlist').sortable("toArray");
alert(result);
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTzCS/74/)